# multipart/form-data request - servlet - request.getPart() gives null pointer exception

Tags: tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception, multipartform-data, multipart

We are facing a strange problem wherein we are getting a null pointer exception for a multipart/form-data request. We have a servlet which is configured to handle multipart/form-data request. Exception comes at request.getPart() or request.getParameter(). The issue happens only with multipart/form-data request; we are trying with a smaller file size. We are running our app in Tomcat 9.0.73 in linux machine. And we are not seeing this error in eclipse and in lifecycles other than Development. We have other apps deployed in same tomcat server, where upload works. Uploads were working fine and we noticed this error recently. And we do not have any config/code change done related to this.
Below is the stack trace which we are seeing in the app logs

> FileUploadServlet: Error in doPost() : java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2870)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2741)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:796)
> at com.app.controller.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:38)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:528)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
> at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
> at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
> at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:155)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Below is the servlet code

```
@WebServlet()
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024, maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 30, maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 30 * 30)
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Part file = req.getPart("file");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            String expection = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
            log.info("Error in doPost() : " + expection);
        }
    }
}
```

We verified the configuration of tomcat (against the tomcat setting where this is working); do not see anything different. We have gone over the Request.java source to see if there's anything missing; all looks good. Exception is thrown at line 2870 - where we do not see a reason for exception to be thrown

```
   parameters.addParameter(name, value);
```

We did try removing the MultipartConfig annotation, which resulted in an exception - noMultipartConfig as per line 2772 of Request.java, this was done to see request hasn't lost its "multipart" nature.

Any thoughts to share?

Comment: Probably your linux host uses an APM? Googling the exception gives this clue https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/issues/5298